# FilePicker: How to know the source of uploading

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I'm using filepicker in my application.
After uploading it is returning a Blob object with details like size, name.

How can i get Uploading source type from this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Uploading source type", can you clarify?

Comment: @Pekka웃, Like "Google Drive", "Computer"

Comment: Currently, there is no such an option.